# How many datapoints are there generally in terrain height maps?

Tags: terrain, heightmap

I've created my own heightmap with data from USGS. The heightmap is pretty large, but the point density is low, resulting in a low-poly terrain.

While performance is excellent, the physics engine I'm using doesn't particularly like how much distance is between each point, resulting in clipping.

Regardless, what is the point density like for games like H1Z1 or any other game that uses a height map on a large world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a specific standard for point density, for a few good reasons. However, in my experience, a descent density is about 3-7 points per m^2.

The reason that there isn't a standard is because point density varies a lot, based on things like distance and render quality.

For example, the highest quality setting might have 2, 3 or even 4 times as many polygons as the lowest. Also, there is no need to have high point density in a section/chunk of the world that is far away from the player.

Comment: Thanks for the estimate and the explanation! It's exactly what I needed.